# Community Builder Aloha Template login logout

Tags: community, community-builder

Im currently trying to create a coomunity page with the Aloha Template. I need to show logout/settings button in the header and as far as i have come to understand from the documentation 'Getting Started with the Aloha Community Template for Salesforce Identity' there is a component called Identity Header which actually provides all that - but i cannot find it in the components section ? Is it somehow a bug or do i have to make some other configurations to see it here?

Answer (score 0):

In Aloha template there is already a profile header provided. You can view that in community Builder Settings. This header will be available for your community until you delete it or you edit the head markup. Please note that, this Component is a prebuilt one and can be dragged to where you want to show the same. you can also delete the same.

Regards,
Alsinan

Comment: Thanks for the response - i actually found that out that Aloha has actually that identity header - but i deleted that and i can only get it back when i create a whole new community. That really makes working hard.